# Finding all non-repeated elements in list

Tags: python

I want my input to be any random numbers in any number of elements.
Examples:

1. ```
   Input: 1 2 3 4 1
   Output: 2 3 4
   ```
2. ```
   Input: 4 3 5 2 5 1 3 5
   Output: 4 2 1
   ```
3. ```
   Input: 5 5 2 6 7 7 9 9 3 3 4 1
   Output: 2 6 4 1
   ```

```py
from collections import defaultdict

n = int(input(""))
print("")
array = 0

def single_element(array, n):
    table = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i in range(0,n):
        array[i] = int(input(""))
        table[array[i]] += 1
        if table[array[i]] == 1:
            print(array[i], end="")
            return ""


print(single_element(array,n))
```

Are there ways to improve this?

When I run the program, this appears:

```
line 17, in <module>
    print(single_element(array,n))
line 10, in single_element
    array[i] = int(input(""))
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Code review is a site to seek peer review for working code. If your code is not working correctly, it is unfortunately off-topic for this site. You might try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you can word the question in a way that fits the criteria on that page. Once your code works correctly, you're welcome to ask a new question here and we can then help you improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `cnt = collections.Counter(array)` to count the number of occurrences per element. Then return `[element for element in array if cnt[element] == 1`.

Comment: Nice simple answer. I downvote only to discourage answering off-topic questions.